# What statistical analysis can I use to assess whether different groups use different themes in chat conversations?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, categorical-encoding

Currently, I’m analyzing publicly available chats of 3 groups of people. Within these chats, I label lines for themes 1-5. Any single line could fall under multiple of the five themes so for instance:

“Hey how are you” could be themes 1,3, and 5.

I want to assess whether or not the three groups use different themes. Originally, I thought I could use Chi square and look at the total amount of each theme used by each of three groups. However, I do not believe that will work because each line of each chat could be labeled more than once as in the example above.

Does anyone know of a statistical analysis that would work for this? Any help would be great!